# ACF have_rows not finding data when using post id inside acf block

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using acf to create gutenberg blocks and am running into an issue that I have not seen before. I am looking to pull repeater data from another page using the page id but I can not get the data to show. Here is my code:

```
$page_id = get_field('registration_page');

if(have_rows('form_steps', $page_id)) :
    echo '<div class="form-steps">';
        echo '<div class="step-line"></div>';
        echo '<div class="step-fill" style="width:900px;"></div>';
        while(have_rows('form_steps', $page_id)) : the_row();
            echo '<div class="step confirmed">';
                echo '<div class="icon"><img src="'.get_sub_field('icon').'" /></div>';
                echo '<div class="step-label">'.get_sub_field('label').'</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        endwhile;
    echo'</div>';
endif;
```

I have echoed out $page_id and it shows the correct post id and this code works perfectly if it is using on the actual page the fields are located on without the extra id call. It only doesnt display if the optional id parameter is added. Any help or ideas why this would not output the data is appreciated.

Comment: So, `$post_id` returns the post id of the page you want to pull data from, but when you use the `$post_id` in the `have_rows`, you aren't getting the repeater data from that other page? Is the repeater block in a custom gutenberg block?

Comment: Its in an acf block.

Comment: What about my other questions? It seems you are trying to pull repeater data associated with a block on a page. If that's the case, this won't work, because you need the ID of the block not the page.

Comment: So your saying that the acf data from a page inside a block is not associated with that page so I would have to find the block id of the block with the specific page id?

Comment: Blocks have their own IDs. The fields (`form_steps` in your case) in a block are not associated with the ID of the page. So, you can't use the page ID to get ACF fields of a block. You need to get the ID of the actual block.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I had to parse the blocks using the post id then loop through and echo the form steps data.